# How can I delete all message except 1 specific message with a message ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know how to delete all messages:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "clearchat")) {
    async function clear() {
        message.delete();
        const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 99});
        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
    }
    clear();
}
```

However, I don't know how to prevent a message with a specific ID from being deleted. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Collection.prototype.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=delete). Since messages are keyed by their IDs, it makes it easy to delete them.

```js
const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 99 });
fetched.delete('Message ID');
message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
```